# Extract Integer Part in String

Tags: java, string, parsing, integer, java.util.scanner

What is the best way to extract the integer part of a string like

```
Hello123
```

How do you get the 123 part. You can sort of hack it using Java's Scanner, is there a better way?

Comment: Will there ever be an instance like "123Hello456" ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why don't you just use a Regular Expression to match the part of the string that you want?

```
[0-9]
```

That's all you need, plus whatever surrounding chars it requires.

Look at http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html to understand how Regular expressions work.

Edit:  I'd like to say that Regex may be a little overboard for this example, if indeed the code that the other submitter posted works... but I'd still recommend learning Regex's in general, for they are very powerful, and will come in handy more than I'd like to admit (after waiting several years before giving them a shot).

Answer (score 47):

As explained before, try using Regular Expressions. This should help out:

```
String value = "Hello123";
String intValue = value.replaceAll("[^0-9]", ""); // returns 123
```

And then you just convert that to an int (or Integer) from there.

Comment: I actually had to do value.replaceAll("[A-z]+", "");

Comment: @MasterHD - did you include the caret? I just ran this and it returns "123" just fine.

Answer (score 26):

I believe you can do something like:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner("Hello123").useDelimiter("[^0-9]+");
int integer = in.nextInt();
```

EDIT: Added useDelimiter suggestion by Carlos

Comment: In what namespave can i find Scanner.

Comment: Yeah, it's not necessarily the sleekest or most elegant way to go, but it should work. It's even used in the scanner documentation at http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: The documentation for `nextInt` states "This method will throw InputMismatchException if the next token cannot be translated into a valid int" which is the case for `Hello123`. Can use `in.useDelimiter("[^0-9]+");` to *ignore* non-digits

Comment: Good point. Sorry about that. Missed the default delimiter stuff. That's what I get for not trying it out first.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you want a trailing digit, this would work:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Example {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\D*(\\d*)");
        String input = "Hello123";
        Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(input);

        if (matcher.matches() && matcher.groupCount() == 1) {
            String digitStr = matcher.group(1);
            Integer digit = Integer.parseInt(digitStr);
            System.out.println(digit);            
        }

        System.out.println("done.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, it would work for your example and for "small" numbers. It will clearly fail for large numbers that won't fit into an int.

Answer (score 4):

I had been thinking Michael's regex was the simplest solution possible, but on second thought just "\d+" works if you use Matcher.find() instead of Matcher.matches():

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "Hello123";
        int output = extractInt(input);

        System.out.println("input [" + input + "], output [" + output + "]");
    }

    //
    // Parses first group of consecutive digits found into an int.
    //
    public static int extractInt(String str) {
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher(str);

        if (!matcher.find())
            throw new NumberFormatException("For input string [" + str + "]");

        return Integer.parseInt(matcher.group());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Although I know that it's a 6 year old question, but I am posting an answer for those who want to avoid learning regex right now(which you should btw). This approach also gives the number in between the digits(for eg. HP**123**KT**567** will return 123567)

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.print("Enter alphaNumeric: ");
    String x = scan.next();
    String numStr = "";
    int num;

    for (int i = 0; i < x.length(); i++) {
        char charCheck = x.charAt(i);
        if(Character.isDigit(charCheck)) {
            numStr += charCheck;
        }
    }

    num = Integer.parseInt(numStr);
    System.out.println("The extracted number is: " + num);
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me perfectly.

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("string1234more567string890");
    while(m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
```

OutPut:

```
1234
567
890
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] parts = s.split("\\D+");    //s is string containing integers
int[] a;
a = new int[parts.length];
for(int i=0; i<parts.length; i++){
a[i]= Integer.parseInt(parts[i]);
System.out.println(a[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can simply use regular expression to extract the integer value from string

```
String str= "HEll1oTe45st23";
String intValue = str.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
System.out.print(Integer.parseInt(intValue));
```

Here, you can replaceAll string values with empty values and then parse the string to integer value. Further, you can use integer values.