# Regular expression to retreieve integer

Tags: java, regex, string

Hi I have an URL like "/yyyyyy/xm", where x can be an integer denoting the number of minutes. I need to parse and get this value. Any idea of how this can be using regex or String.split() method? The pattern of the URL is always the same like for example:

```
/magnetic/20m should give me the value 20
/temperature/500m should give me the value 500
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The following Url can help you in finding your answer.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903252/extract-integer-part-in-string

Comment: What have you tried? What does your attempt look like? Where are you running into trouble?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should work:

```
/.*?/(\d+)
```

You just need to access to the 1st group of the match, and you'll get the numbers there.

**Edit:**
In the future, finding the regex by yourself. That's a pretty straightforward regex question.

Comment: there should be `m` after `(\d+)` else it would also match `www.site.com/123`

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ two things: 1) are you sure? I only see one `/` on `www.site.com/123` and 2) suppose it matches `www.site.com/123`, then it would match `www.site.com/123m` too. I think you should design regular expressions in an specific context. Do you know if he is trying to parse a file where each line only has `/some-text/XXXXm`?

Answer (score 1):

And if you don't like regexp...

```
        String txt = "/magnetic/20m";
        String[] components = txt.split("/");
        String lastComponent = components[components.length - 1];
        int result = Integer.parseInt(lastComponent.replace("m", ""));
```