# Fetching Long Value From String

Tags: java, android, regex, string, replace

Thanks for Your Valuable time. I need to explode my string and fetch only digit before Kr. (In Java)

Example `String str = "Delhi     205 Kr."`

From above I need only 205 as substring.

Another Problem is that suppose i get another digit in that string then again i need only digit before space Kr.

Example `String str = "India112Delhi     98 Kr."`

Here I also need 98 not 112 or combination of both.

And if I have String like this then how to retrieve value 25 only?

String str = "New Delhi113    25 Kr."

Please help me out
**Thanks in Advance.**

Comment: Can you answer please.. Dont have time to study deep.

Comment: If you don't have time, at least look at the `split()` method in the `String` class. It is easy to understand and will probably do the work for you here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extract Integer Part in String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903252/extract-integer-part-in-string)

Answer (score 1):

Just split the String using split function, which will give you array of strings. Loop over it and try parsing each string in the array. Put the parsing code in try{}catch{} if the parsing was successfull, you got your number. else continue looping.

```
String str = "Delhi 205 Kr.";
```

String[] values = str.split(" ");

Long value=0;

```
 for(int i=0; i<values.length; i++)
    {
            try {
                value = Long.parseLong(values[i]);
    break;
            }
        catch(Exception e)
        {}
    }
}
System.out.println(value);
```

Comment: Only catches first number thats surrounded by spaces. What if the number before kr is the 2nd number in the string?

Comment: @Hardik4560 See the edited question please. What to do now

Comment: Same answer of mine will work as 113 is not having any spaces in between. This code will work for all the numbers surrounded by spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex as a pattern:

`(\d+) (K|k)(R|r)\.`

And get the value of the first group from your `Matcher`.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\d+) (K|k)(R|r)\.");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("India112Delhi 98 Kr.");

if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With your given sample code (Note this will work only when you need to get the unit from the Second place)

```
String str = "Delhi 205 Kr.";
String[] values = str.split(" ");
Long value = Long.parseLong(values[1]);
```

**UPDATED**

```
String str = "Delhi 205 Kr.";
String[] values = str.split(" ");

Long value=0;
for(int i=1; i<values.length; i++)
{
    if(values[i].equalsIgnoreCase("kr."))
    {
        try {
            value = Long.parseLong(values[i-1]);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Not a number before Kr");
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(value);
```

**NOTE** The second code will get the value before the 'Kr'.

Comment: Exactly what I said in my answer, u can ignore the if check

Comment: Anyways `if` check does not add to the time complexity, to be precise the Big-Oh. Moreover why to throw the exception in anyway, when it can be easily checked

Comment: This won't work if the string is "112 washinton dc", the number 112 will never be retrieved. Please check my answer, and give your opinion

Comment: @VarunVishnoi Updated my answer as it had Kr. [I missed the period]

Comment: @Hardik4560 If you see OP question, he clearly specified _i need only digit before space Kr._

Comment: @asifsid88 yes u r right i need numeric value befor space Kr.

Comment: Yes, I did checked the question only thing while answering is, it was generic, can fit into any condition and not only before "kr". Any ways it solved.

Answer (score 0):

Some code that uses [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/), my Java framework of choice :)

```
String str = "..."; // input string

int indexOf = str.indexOf("Kr"); // get the index of Kr
String previous = str.substring(0, indexOf); // only get string before kr

// Split string on all non-digits and throw away any empty splits. 
// This leaves you with only numbers
Iterable<String> numbers = Splitters.onPattern("\\D").omitEmptyStrings();
// Get the last of the numbers since this one is next to the Kr.
Long output = Long.parseLong(Iterables.getLast(numbers));
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey thanks to all but the real and correct answer is here. We need to loop from back

```
                    String cost= "Nay String   205 Kr.";
                    String[] values = cost.split(" ");
                    Long value=(long) 0;
                    for(int i=values.length; i>0; i--)
                    {
                            try {
                                value = Long.parseLong(values[i]);
                    break;
                            }
                        catch(Exception e)
                        {}
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Will this work for you?


`String str = "India112Delhi 98 Kr.";`

String []  strarray = str.split(" ");

System.out.println(Long.parseLong(strarray[strarray.length-2]));

Answer (score -1):

This solution only applies if your input strings are always in the same format.

You could split the string based on spaces.

Something equivalent to:

string.split(' ')

For input string **India112Delhi 98 Kr.** you would obtain an array that looks like:

*[India112Delhi, 98, Kr.]*

Your second last element would always be the number you need!