# Java separating String and Integer

Tags: java, string, int

Hi all I am hoping to strip a string in Java into a String and an integer for example:

```
"String1"
```

into:

```
String StringName = "String";
int StringInt = 1;
```

the Strings also may vary in length, is there an easy way to do this in Java, apologies if easy complete newbie.

Comment: any logic from your side ?

Comment: In this case regex woud be nice:)

Comment: I accidentally posted an answer without seeing your effort. :) Have you got anything in your mind as a solution? You have to show it...

Comment: To extract number from string, check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903252/extract-integer-part-in-string

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would suggest to use the regular expression.

```
String value = "string12asd";
String intValue = value.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
String stringValue = value.replaceAll("[0-9]","");
System.out.println("int are: "+intValue+" \n string are: "+stringValue);
```

Look at http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html for more detail about regular expression.

Comment: For this question I think regex is a little overkill.

Comment: Why ? he did not mentioned where the integer or string is gonna come

Comment: Why does it matter where the integer and string come from? A regular expression will have to iterate through the entire string while a more direct approach will only have to iterate over the number at the end.

Comment: This solution is horrible! What about `StringWith1DigitBeforeEnd123`?

Comment: I got correct result for StringWith1DigitBeforeEnd123

Comment: @Ashish And what is the result you got? By the way, it's usually not a good idea to downvote everyone else's answer just because yours got downvoted.

Comment: I got int are: 1123 string are: StringWithDigitBeforeEnd for "StingWith1DigitBeforeEnd123" which I think is correct

Comment: No,that is definitely not correct. In what situation would you want to combine the numbers in a string like that?

Comment: @Ashish Your result will show `1123` which - I assume - is not the desired result. I think @Michael has a good point there too. I expect `123`. Also think about `StringWithNasty#InIt9`. Your code would result in an exception when trying to convert the intValue string to an integer.

Comment: and I did not downvote, I don't care about that

Comment: @SebastianH, I will improve the code # good catch thanks

Comment: You didn't change your answer. Are you just going to leave it as-is since you already got your check or actually update your answer?

Comment: @Ashish It's still wrong.

Comment: why can you please give me some use case.

Comment: The same problem as before is occurring, if you provide the string `StringWith1DigitBeforeEnd123` you will get back `1123`, which is wrong. In this case the user would want `StringWith1DigitBeforeEnd` and `123`. The only thing you actually fixed with your edit was the crash when a string such as `StringWithNasty#InIt9` is used.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47988/discussion-between-ashish-and-michael)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a regular expression: `(.*?)(\\d+)$`
Let me explain this starting at the end. `$` matches the end of the string (I am not considering multi line strings here). `\d` (in java code needs to be escaped as `\\d`) matches any digit, so the last capturing group matches the integer at the end of the string. The first group matches all characters in front of that. A non-greedy evaluation `*?` is required in the first group, otherwise it would just match the whole string.

As a whole working example:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(.*?)(\\d+)$").matcher(yourString);
if (m.matches()) {
    String stringPart = m.group(1);
    int intPart = Integer.parseInt(m.group(2));
}
```

Comment: Honestly I'm not sure. My post got downvoted as soon as I disagreed with Ashish in the comment thread of his post, and about a minute after someone downvoted his post the rest of them got a -1 as well.

Answer (score 1):

If the number is always at the end of your string, write a method that iterates through the string starting from the end until you hit a non-integer character and then take the substring using the index you've just found. This will probably be faster than regex in most cases since iterating through the end of the string will be `O(n)` (where `n=[num_integers]`) + `O(1)` for the `substring` method.

Answer (score 1):

```
String stringName[<maximum length>]
int stringInt;
for( int i = 0; i < originalString.length(); i++){
   if(isDigit(originalString[i]){
      stringInt = originalString[i];
   }
   else{
      stringName[i] = originalString[i];
   }
}
```

This should move all characters from your original string into stringName unless an integer value comes along which will be save in stringInt