# How to pick up only integer data from an ArrayList of String

Tags: java, arraylist, integer, double, benfords-law

I read a text file and put the data into an `ArrayList` of `String`.

The data is like

```
China 12351235123 Korea 123532523 USA 12341235123
```

I just need those integer data as an integer to find the first digit of the integers. I know how to find the first digit, but I don't know how I can pick up only the integer data.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: ArrayList of String won't accept Integers. It's may be ArrayList of Objects. Is it ? OR "China 12351235123" is a single String ?

Comment: Maybe [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903252/extract-integer-part-in-string) can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that your `ArrayList` is of type `String`. `replaceAll()` will take out anything that isn't a number(0-9)

```
ArrayList<String> countrys = new ArrayList<String>();
countrys.add("China 12351235123");
countrys.add("Korea 123532523");
countrys.add("USA 12341235123");

for(String c:countrys){
    String number = c.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
    System.out.println(number);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! that can be a way!

Comment: I don't need those string data, but I just need integer data to find a first digit of them.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
  // Creation of ArrayList of string
  ArrayList<String> obj = new ArrayList<String>();

  // arrayList of string
  obj.add("China 12351235123");
  obj.add("Korea 123532523");
  obj.add("USA 12341235123");


    Iterator<String> iterator = obj.iterator();
    String str;
    String[] split_str;
    long  value;
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        str = iterator.next().toString();
        split_str = str.split(" ");
        String split_2 = split_str[1];
        value = Long.parseLong(split_2);
        System.out.println(value);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex as SLY suggested, or you can go over your list and split the object into two parts: 'country' and 'number' using:

```
for(String s : array){
    String[] parts = s.split(" ");
    long number = Long.parseLong(parts[1]);
    System.out.println(number);
}
```

**NOTE**: the invariant is that each element contains two parts with the delimiter 'white space', and the second part is a number.

Comment: I don't need those string data, but I just need integer data to find a first digit of them .

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex and would be careful that not all that numbers can be in a integer range... so there for  the list of longs in the code below

## Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Long> longList = new ArrayList<Long>();
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\w+([0-9]+)");// regex pattern
    for (String string : listOfCountriesAndNumbers) {
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
        for (int i = 0; i < matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
            matcher.find();
            longList.add(Long.parseLong(matcher.group()));
        }
    }
    System.out.println(longList);
}
```