# Extracting integers from a string and store them in separate variables in java with substring and lastIndexOf(" ") methods

Tags: java, file, integer, store

I'm having an issue with this particular program. To cut a long story short, what this program is supposed to do is to get input from a text file, in this case the names and scores of bowlers, and read data off of it. The issue I'm having is trying to extract the scores from the file and storing them in separate variables. 
`

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class lab5{
    public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException {

            String bowler;

            String name;


           int score1 = 0, score2 = 0, score3 = 0;
             int game = 0;
             int average = 0;

          //Scanner scan = new Scanner (new FileReader("bowl1.txt."));
            Scanner scan = new Scanner (new File ("bowl1.txt"));

               while (scan.hasNext()){
                   bowler = scan.nextLine();
                System.out.println("\n" + bowler);

                String charCheck = "";
                String indent = "";

               int count = bowler.length() - 1;


                 while (count <= bowler.length()){

                   indent = bowler.lastIndexOf(" ");



                  charCheck = bowler.substring(0,indent);

                  System.out.println(charCheck);

                 count++; 


                   score1 = Integer.parseInt(charCheck);
                     score2 = Integer.parseInt(charCheck);
                   score3 = Integer.parseInt(charCheck);                          
                 }//end while 

                    System.out.println(score1 + score2 + score3); 


         }//end fileScan while 

     }//end main

    }//end class
```

I apologize that my code is a bit sloppy, but I am still learning some of the basics of java. Basically, the idea here is that I need to use the Substring and  lastIndexOf(" ") methods to read the scores from the file, and then using Integer.parseInt() to turn them into integers.

(The file is called "bowl1.txt", and this is the data on it)

> Atkison, Darren 188 218 177
>   Barnes, Chris 202 194 195
>   Dolan, Anthony 203 193 225
>   Easton, Charles 255 213 190

Any help or hints on what I'm missing would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This link may be useful to you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903252/extract-integer-part-in-string

Answer (score 0):

When you call `bowler.substring(0, indent)` you actually substring the name of the bowler, so it doesn't contains the scores.

If you want to get only the scores part of the string, use `bowler.substring(indent + 1, bowler.length)`. You still have to break it to 3 different strings and convert each one of them into a integer.

Anyway, a better approach will be to split each line into an array of strings using [String#split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) print the first strings, since it is the bowler name and then convert the last 3 into integers. You can also use [Scanner#nextInt()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) and [Scanner#nextString()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) methods, since the structure of the file is known.

Comment: Thanks. I would've used the split method myself, but it was required of me to go the more complicated route for whatever reason.

Answer (score 0):

Introduced a class Bowler to store each row of data. You can now use the list of bowler objects to continue your process. String.split() gives an array of Strings tokenized based on the character specified. Space has been used here to split.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class lab5 {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("C:\\TEMP\\bowl1.txt"));
        String bowler;
        List<Bowler> bowlers = new ArrayList<Bowler>();
        while (scan.hasNext()) {
            bowler = scan.nextLine();
            if (!bowler.trim().equals("")) {
                System.out.println("\n" + bowler);
                String[] tokens = bowler.split(" ");
                Bowler b = new Bowler(tokens[0], tokens[1], Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]), Integer.parseInt(tokens[3]),
                        Integer.parseInt(tokens[4]));
                bowlers.add(b);
            }
        } // end fileScan while
        for (Bowler bow : bowlers) {
            System.out.println(bow.score1 + ", " + bow.score2 + ", " + bow.score3);
        }
    }// end main

}// end class

class Bowler {
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    int score1;
    int score2;
    int score3;

    public Bowler(String firstName, String lastName, int score1, int score2, int score3) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.score1 = score1;
        this.score2 = score2;
        this.score3 = score3;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay this is a straight forward method....it is done only using lastIndexOf(" ") and substring("") method as you said. but there are lot efficient and more easy ways as Narayana Ganesh mentioned above....this method also can be more
precised if you want....

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

```
public class test2
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    String bowler;
    String name;
    int score1 = 0, score2 = 0, score3 = 0;
    int game = 0;
    int average = 0;

    String filename = "bowl1.txt";
    File textfile = new File(filename);

    try{

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(textfile);

        while (scan.hasNextLine()){

            bowler = scan.nextLine();
            System.out.println("\n" + bowler);
            String text1 = "";
            String text2 = "";
            int index=0;

            int length = bowler.length();

            index = bowler.lastIndexOf(" ");
            text1 = bowler.substring(0,index);
            text2 = bowler.substring(index+1,length);
            score1 = Integer.parseInt(text2);

            length = text1.length();    
            index = text1.lastIndexOf(" ");
            text2 = text1.substring(index+1,length);
            text1 = text1.substring(0,index);
            score2 = Integer.parseInt(text2);

            length = text1.length();
            index = text1.lastIndexOf(" ");
            text2 = text1.substring(index+1,length);
            text1 = text1.substring(0,index);
            score3 = Integer.parseInt(text2);           

            System.out.println(score1);
            System.out.println(score2);
            System.out.println(score3);
            System.out.println("Total:"+(score1 + score2 + score3)); 
        }
    }catch(FileNotFoundException e){};
}
}
```