# Print the integers in the given Input String

Tags: java, regex

***I got the correct output for the below code. Is there any other way that could solve the problem?***

*For example **input**:Hai 88 Hello **output:** 88*

```
    package stringint;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class StringInt 
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            String name = scan.nextLine();
            name = name.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z]","@"); //replacing the 
                                                   //alphabets to "@"
            String[] array = name.split(" "); 
            for(int i = 0;i<array.length;i++)
            {
                if(!array[i].contains("@")) 
                {
                    System.out.println(array[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @GBlodgett : No i got the correct output. But I need to know is there any better way to solve this program.

Comment: Are those spaces relevant? `"w!h4t3v3r_".replaceAll("[^0-9]", "")` would give you `433` and nothing with your code. What's the desired behavior or is the input known to contain only "words" that are either numbers or characters?

Comment: Just replace all non digits  `name = name.replaceAll("\\D+","");` instead of replacing with another character and then looping it. This return you only digits

Comment: @Abarna.N you should use this:  "33w!hs.kdkdjhda4t3v3r_".replaceAll("[^\d]", "")

Comment: If your input was: `Hai 88 77 Hello` would you want `8877` or `88 77`? As @zapl asked, do you want to preserve "groups" or numbers, or run all the numbers together? In his comment, would you want `433` or `4 3 3`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract Integer Part in String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903252/extract-integer-part-in-string)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I just replaced those Alphabets with nothing

```
package stringint;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class StringInt 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name = scan.nextLine();
        name = name.replaceAll("[\\D+]",""); //replacing all non-numeric char with nothing.
        System.out.println(name);
    }
}
```

All I did was to replace the Alphabets with an empty string and then displace the result which is the variable `name` instead of `looping`.

Here is a working example of the above [code](https://ideone.com/gempEg).

Comment: This solution will output non-numbers for some inputs: `Home: 12, Visitor: 9` would output `: 12, : 9`

Comment: how about other characters in string ? e.g. `hai 88*12@#%%^bbcb. this ?`

Comment: This is `regex` expected in the Question, I didn't want to change the functionality of the Code which is required by @Abarna.N

Comment: The requirement is _"to print the integers in the given input string"_ ... if the whole output was just `System.out.println(input)` that would, in fact, print the integers in the input string -- but it would also print other non-integer things, which is clearly not the intent given the stated expected output of `88`. The requirement statement (the specification) is insufficient to fully answer the question, but I would assume _"to print **only** the integers in the given input"_.  NullPointerException's comment on the question would do that. This will not.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you will not get correct output if your input string is like "abc 12 @ &! ab bb 54 n 2"

In this case you will also get all other extra chars other than alphabets.
Try This code given Below. Hope it will help..

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{     

        String nam = "abc 12 @ &! ab bb 54 n 2";
        Pattern p1=Pattern.compile("\\d");
        Matcher m1= p1.matcher(nam);
        List<String>listOfNumbr= new ArrayList<>();
        boolean chck=true;
        int start=0;
        int end=0;
        do{
            if(chck==true){
                chck=false;
                if(m1.find()){
                    start=m1.start();
                    String sub=nam.substring(start);
                     Pattern p2=Pattern.compile("\\D");
                      Matcher m2= p2.matcher(sub);
                      if(m2.find()){
                          end=m2.start();
                      }else{
                          end=sub.length();
                      }
                    String numbr=sub.substring(0,end);
                    listOfNumbr.add(numbr);
                    nam=sub.substring(end);
                    m1=p1.matcher(nam);
                }
            }else{

                start=m1.start();
                String sub=nam.substring(start);
                 Pattern p2=Pattern.compile("\\D");
                  Matcher m2= p2.matcher(sub);
                  if(m2.find()){
                      end=m2.start();
                  }else{
                      end=sub.length();
                  }
                String numbr=sub.substring(0,end);
                listOfNumbr.add(numbr);
                nam=sub.substring(end);
                m1=p1.matcher(nam);
            }
        }    while(m1.find());


    for(String str:listOfNumbr){
        System.out.println(str);
    }
```

This will give all the numeric values within the String.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's easier to do this:

```
String name = "Hai 88 Hello";
String[] digits = name.split("\\D+");
List<Integer> nums = Arrays.stream(digits).filter(s -> !s.isEmpty()).map(Integer::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(nums); //[88]
```