# I want to extract integers from a input string "a2re45pr456#$#$80"

Tags: java, string

input string : "a2re45pr456#$#$80"

I should get a output like below

output : 2+45+456+80 = 583

Comment: [Extract all integers from the given string in Java](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/extract-all-integers-from-the-given-string-in-java/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract Integer Part in String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903252/extract-integer-part-in-string)

Comment: `int sum = Stream.of(input.split("[^\\d]+")).filter(part -> !part.isEmpty()).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).sum()`.